# phpmyadmin пустая страница

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, vps

Установил php 8.0.16 и последнюю версию phpmyadmin на VPS. Когда зашел в phpmyadmin, увидел пустую страницу

В error.log apache никаких ошибок.

В интернете пишут, что им помогла установка `php-gettext`, но когда я пытаюсь установить, у меня ошибка:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php-gettext
```

Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение. В интернете нигде не было об этом написано.

Если установлено несколько версий php или было обновление php, то нужно заново установить модули, указав текущею версию:

```
sudo apt install phpmyadmin php8.0-mbstring php8.0-zip php8.0-gd php-json php8.0-curl
```